# hide and show features using jquery

Tags: arrays, loops, hide, show, target

I need some help. I'm designing a website. In home page, there are several links. With the help of jquery, I want to hide and show content (on the same page) depending on the links which the user clicks. 
I have achieved it, but I feel; its not the right approach. Is there anyway to achieve this with minimal code? may be using arrays or loops? Please have a look at the example that I have created. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$('.para2').hide();
$('.para3').hide();

<!--One-->

$('.one').click(function(){

$('.para1').show();

$('.para2').hide();
$('.para3').hide();

})


<!--Two-->

$('.two').click(function(){

$('.para2').show();

$('.para1').hide();
$('.para3').hide();

})


<!--three-->


$('.three').click(function(){

$('.para3').show();

$('.para1').hide();
$('.para2').hide();

})

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="one"  >Para -1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="two"  >Para -2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="three"  >Para -3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="para1" style="width:500px; padding:10px; border:1px solid red; background:#009966">
  <h1>Para -1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor purus at massa venenatis nec facilisis lectus volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Proin facilisis, nisl a auctor venenatis, metus nisi congue tortor, quis laoreet nisl magna in massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>

  <div class="para2" style="width:500px; padding:10px; border:1px solid red; background:#333333">
  <h1>Para -2</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor purus at massa venenatis nec facilisis lectus volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Proin facilisis, nisl a auctor venenatis, metus nisi congue tortor, quis laoreet nisl magna in massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>

  <div class="para3" style="width:500px; padding:10px; border:1px solid red;">
  <h1>Para -3</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor purus at massa venenatis nec facilisis lectus volutpat. Suspendisse potenti. Proin facilisis, nisl a auctor venenatis, metus nisi congue tortor, quis laoreet nisl magna in massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change like below:

Html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="paraLink" data-para="one" >Para -1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="paraLink" data-para="two" >Para -2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="paraLink" data-para="three" >Para -3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="para one" ...
<div class="para two" ...
<div class="para three" ...
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.paraLink').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.para').hide();
      $('.'+$(this).data('para')).show();
  });
});
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/c7epF/)**

Comment: Thank you for you answer. its great, however, I forgot to mention that I want the first para to be dsiplayed ( as i don't want the page empty with links), when clicked it should replace. I tried this but it didnt work         
  $('.para one ').show();
    $('.para two ').hide();
  $('.para three ').hide();